# On submit, after X seconds, if window blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, onblur

I am trying to identify if the window loses focus after 3 seconds of submit.

Currently I have this:

```
$("input").on("submit",function(){
$(window).blur(function(){
  console.log(a);
})
});
```

But this, no matter when you press submit, if you click outside the window or minimize the window the `console.log` triggers `a`.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. User submits form
2. In a period of 3 seconds, if the window loses focus do console.log(a);
3. After 3 seconds, if the window loses focus **do nothing.**
4. If the user submits again on the same session, repeat from step 1.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. Do you want the blur function to fire if the window is blurred after 3 seconds?

Comment: When you submit, if in a 3 seconds period the window loses focus, trigger console.log(a)

Comment: And after the 3 seconds, you don't want the blur to fire?

Comment: Yes, unless if the input is submitted again (wait another 3 seconds).
The idea is sometimes the form opens in a new tab and sometimes not. The user determines whether to open results in a new tab or not. So i want to identify if its opened or not. The way I am using it right now, even if results open in a new tab or not, when the user changes tab or minimize (loses focus of the window), console.log(a) is triggered.

Comment: How `input` can be submitted?

Comment: @Jonathan Then the `form` is submitted, not `input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#form").on("submit",function(){
    var blurFunc = function() {
        console.log(a);
    }

    $(window).blur(blurFunc);
    setTimeout(function() { $(window).unbind('blur', blurFunc); }, 3000);
});
```

The `setTimeout` call will unbind from the blur event after 3 seconds, causing the event to not fire.

For more info on `setTimeout` see here: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
$("#form").on("submit",function(){
    var submitted = true;

    var blurFunc = function() {
        if(submitted) {
            console.log(a);
        } 
    }

    $(window).blur(blurFunc);
    setTimeout(function() { submitted = false; }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but I thought they wanted it the other way around: The `blur` should do nothing if it's within three seconds, otherwise it should do whatever.

Comment: I wouldnt want to use bind or unbind. That is why I havent used this method. I do know what setTimeout is but I wasnt sure which would be the best or more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist see comments on the OP's question.

Comment: -1 because (a) using a string with `setTimeout` is Bad and (b) you're not using `unbind` well in this case (you're unbinding all unbind handlers, rather than just the one you set above).

Comment: @lonesomeday thanks for the feedback.  How else do you use setTimeout except with a string?  Every example I've found uses a string, and this is the way I've done it in the past.  Also, good point on the unbind call.

Comment: @lonesomeday I actually didn't get your point. Why string *here* is Bad? And it seems he unbinds only `blur` event, doesn't he?

Comment: @KyleTrauberman `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 3000);` is another option.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman [With a function object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: @VisioN I unbind all blur events.  What if there is another event handler on the window blur, this causes it to be removed as well.

Comment: @Derek Usually true, but why is it EVIL exactly in this situation?

Comment: @KyleTrauberman - Because now it is in GLOBAL, instead of scoped.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman For future reference you can also pass a reference to a declared function, like so: `setTimeout(myFunc, 3000);` where you've declared a function named `myFunc` that implements whatever functionality you want. For this relatively simple case, however, an anonymous function is just as good.

Comment: @Jonathan I think this is the best (if not only) way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Derek But what's the problem in unbinding event in GLOBAL?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.

Comment: @Jonathan I take that back, see my edit for another possible solution.

Comment: @Jonathan Here's a similar jsfiddle using click instead of submit: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZhXn/1/

Comment: Your method doesnt work. No matter how long after, when ever you lose focus of the window, the console triggers

Comment: Even your fiddle is not what I am looking for. Editing my question now

Comment: @Jonathan I used click for simplicity, and it works for me on chrome.  I updated the fiddle as well. http://jsfiddle.net/6nkch/